# Как получить Пользовательские поля?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Есть пользователи в базе BX24 которых я получаю по REST API посредством запроса `user.get`. Полученные данные не содержат прикреплённых пользовательских полей (`UF_*`). Как можно получить пользовательские поля пользователя? Можно и не через REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать REST модуль и обращаться к нему:

```
$filter = isset($params['filter']) ? $params['filter'] : [];
$list   = CUser::GetList($by = '', $order = '', $filter, ['SELECT' => ['*', 'UF_*']]);

while ($fetch = $list->fetch()) {
    static::$users[$fetch['ID']] = $fetch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Работа с пользовательскими полями в битриксе реализована очень плохо, разработчики рекомендуют использовать пользовательские свойства, а не поля. Обновить пользовательское поле (скорее всего любое) можно так:

```
$GLOBALS["USER_FIELD_MANAGER"]->Update("ORDER", $id, Array("UF_CRM_123123"=>$value));
```

- `ORDER` - имя сущности, в данном случае заказ
- `$id` - айди элемента в котором нужно изменить поле
- `UF_CRM_123123` - айди поля
- `$value` - значение